# How to undo setting primary boot device from DISABLED to WINDOWS BOOT LOADER

Tags: boot, bios

Last night I made a huge mistake.  My list of devices in the BIOS boot sequence did not have my CD  ROM listed.  The first device in the boot sequence was WINDOWS BOOT LOADER.  There was USB and a few others in the list.  So I decided to change the primary device in the boot sequence to DISABLED.  Bad mistake on my part.  Now when I boot up the computer, F2 and F12 don't work.  How can I undo the boot sequence so the primary/first is not DISABLED?  Or how can I allow F2 and F12 to function again?

When I boot the machine, I get the following at what looks like a command prompt that is uneditable.  None of the F keys do anything.  Even when rebooting.

```
No boot device available
SATA 0: Installed
SATA 1: None
SATA 2: Installed
SATA 3: None
Strike the F1 key to retry boot, F2 to run the setup utility.
```